# Why do I receive Resource Not Found Exception

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-maven-plugin, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I have an android application that has a maven dependency to an android library project.

In my pom file for the Application, I have referenced the dependency to the apklib like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>lib.CoreResourceResources</artifactId>
        <version>myversion</version>
        <type>apklib</type>
    </dependency>
```

In Android Studio, the IDE allows me to reference the R.java file of that library project like this:

```
my.package.name.core.map.R.string.ok_button_label
```

When I compile my application using android-maven-plugin I receive no errors

```
mvn clean install
```

At runtime when I use my application I receive the following error message:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0200b6
   at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1195)
   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:729)
   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:711)
   at plugins.host.context.PluginResources.getDrawable(PluginResources.java:379)
   at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:15327)
   at my.package.name.core.map.plugins.softbutton.SoftButton.init(SoftButton.java:144)
   at my.package.name.core.map.plugins.softbutton.SoftButton.<init>(SoftButton.
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
   at plugins.host.context.PluginLayoutInflator.createView(PluginLayoutInflator.java:122)
   at plugins.host.context.PluginLayoutInflator.onCreateView(PluginLayoutInflator.java:176)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
   at my.package.name.videoplugin.map.tools.VideoTool.setupDVRView(
   at my.package.name.videoplugin.map.tools.VideoTool.onActivate(
   at transapps.mapi.plugin.ToolManager.activate(ToolManager.java:313)
   at my.package.name.core.map.actions.ToolAction.executeActivate(ToolAction.java:176)
   at my.package.name.core.map.actions.ToolAction.execute(ToolAction.java:158)
   at my.package.name.core.map.plugins.softbutton.SoftButton.handleClick(SoftButton.
   at my.package.name.core.map.plugins.softbutton.SoftButton$2.onClick(SoftButton.
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4445)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18446)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tried clearing my ~/.m2/repository folder to do a fresh clean install and can't seem to get this to work.

I'm using android-maven-plugin 4.3.0 and my host maven version is 3.0.5. Any help or ideas to resolve this issue are appreciated.

The application has been tested on Android 4.4.2 and Android 5.1.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also - using version 3.6.0 of the android-maven-plugin does not cause this issue. However, version 3.6.0 does not support multi-dex which is a must for this application.

Comment: Try with the just released 4.4.0 version. And potentially also check out the pull request that is currently open for improved mutli-dex support.